# Quartz CronTrigger - How Can I Pause a Job and Resume It the Next Day

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, crontrigger

I have a job with a CronTrigger that is set to run once every minute, Monday through Friday: `0 0/1 * ? * MON-FRI`. This job connects to a server and checks a SQL table. Once it finds a given number of rows in the table, it needs to stop checking the table for that day. How would I go about pausing the job after the rows are found and then resuming the job the next day?

The job would thus go something like this:

1. Start checking the table every minute at the beginning of the day.
2. Appropriate number of rows are found. Pause the job for the rest of
   the day.
3. Resume the job at the beginning of the next day.

Comment: You shouldn't use SQL for IPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the job schedule itself every time it runs. If there aren't enough rows, have the job schedule a one time trigger a minute in the future. If it finds enough rows, then have it schedule a trigger for the next day.

You could also do it by pausing and resuming the trigger but then you'll need another job to restart the paused trigger. There isn't a way to pause a trigger for a given amount of time.

Comment: I see. In the case of the first option then, to double check, I would just need to schedule a simple trigger with a start time of midnight? Is there another way to indicate "next day" start time in Quartz?

Comment: That's right. A simple trigger with no repeat starting at midnight if that's what you need. I'm not aware of anything in Quartz.Net to specify next day.